# How can deploy my MERN application on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, mern

I've just deployed my application MERN on Heroku and I used Clever-cloud to deploy my DB and I have a problem my application works for just a while about 5 - 10min after that I get an error H10.

2022-06-08T21:25:55.931817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-08T21:25:55.982112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

Comment: Can you send the error showing in heroku logs ?

Comment: 2022-06-08T21:25:55.802080+00:00 app[web.1]: node:events:505
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802109+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802111+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802111+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802112+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802113+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802113+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)

Comment: ... lines matching original stack trace ...
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802118+00:00 app[web.1]: at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802118+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true,
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802118+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802118+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-06-08T21:25:55.802127+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v18.2.0
2022-06-08T21:25:55.931817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-08T21:25:55.982112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed

Comment: Are you using `mysql.createConnection()` in your code ?

Comment: yes, it connects to mysql without any problem i can use it but after a while the application crash

Comment: Yeah it needs some error handling, that's why officialy they recommend to use `mysql.createPool()` which handles disconnections automatically. Can you try it instead. `const pool = createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'me',
    password : 'secret',
    database : 'my_db'
)};`

Comment: and when i restart the app from the CLI using heroku restart the app works again but for a 5min or 10 max

Comment: Try `createPool()` instead and see if its producing the same issue.

Comment: I waited for a moment if think now it works well, Thank you for your help ;)